# How to get recent edits from GitHub repository without re-cloning?

Tags: git, github, vps

I'm working on a node.js project that I'm hosting on my VPS, so I edit my code on my local PC, then commit it to GitHub. At the moment, to add my changes to my VPS, I delete the old folder and clone it again. The problem with this is that my project uses lots of plugins, so I have to go into the new directory and npm install them all again. Is there a way to just bring in all the changes in the latest commit so it keeps all the plugins installed? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you can't just do - git pull

Comment: oh I'm very new to git, I didn't know about git pull, but I've looked it up and it solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve Tomlin helpfully pointed out, there is a command called `git pull [url]`, so the first time, you use `git clone https://github.com/whoever/whatever.git` to clone it, but when you update the repository, cd inside the cloned repository, and `git pull https://github.com/whoever/whatever.git`. Say you created a new file on GitHub, doing git pull would copy that file onto the client. But also, if in the previous example, on the client you made a new file that you didn't want to commit, `git pull` would leave that file as it is, and would not copy, edit or delete that file. Thanks again to Steve Tomlin.